# Container exit when I run them separately from docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers, microservices

I run the one of the open source microservices from [here](https://github.com/delimitrou/DeathStarBench/tree/master/socialNetwork). When i run docker ps then all the containers status are UP, means they keep running. My issue is when I separately run a container then it did not keep running and exits. Below is one of the service defined in docker-compose file.

```
social-graph-service:

   image: yg397/social-network-microservices
   hostname: social-graph-service
   restart: always
   entrypoint: SocialGraphService
```

when i run it using command

```
sudo docker run -d --restart always --entrypoint SocialGraphService --hostname social-graph-service yg397/social-network-microservices
```

then its status does not UP, it exits after running. Why all the containers run continuously when i run them using sudo docker-compose up? and exit when i run them individually?

Comment: can you share your docker-compose.yml file ?

Comment: ...and the logs from the container, and enough of your application source code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: That entrypoint looks quite suspicious -- can you justify it?

Comment: this is an open source project, available on github https://github.com/delimitrou/DeathStarBench/tree/master/socialNetwork

Comment: When i run it in foreground mode by " sudo docker run --restart always --entrypoint SocialGraphService --hostname social-graph-service yg397/social-network-microservices" then this error occurs "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'  what():  Error resolving address: Name or service not known"

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer what i understand is when DockerFile run, then inside DockerFile it run CMakeLists.txt file; inside this file, it adds the sub-folders from "src" folder, one of which is SocialGraphService.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the graph service depends on MongoDB in order to run. My guess is it crashes when you run it individually because the mongo instance doesn't exist and it fails to connect.

The author of the repo wrote the docker-compose file to hide away some of the complexity from you, but that's a substantial tree of relationships between microservices, and most of them seem to depend on others existing in order to boot up.

-- Update --

The real issue is in the comments below. OP was already running the docker-compose stack while attempting to start another container, but forgot to connect the container to the docker network generated by docker-compose.

Comment: I already run all the services using docker-compose and all these containers running continuously. Now I only run graph service container and i think if graph service depend on mongoB then it will find mongoDB.

Comment: The service can't just _find_ the mongo instance without being provided a hostname, but looks like the repo mounts a global `config/service-config.json` file which includes these hosts. Assuming it's mounted properly then it will be found. However, docker-compose also generates isolated networks for compose stacks. To find the network name, run `docker network ls`. [You can then connect the container to said network at runtime](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/#connect-a-container-to-a-network-when-it-starts)

Comment: it works. My mistake was I did not connect a container with the application network. Now its status is also UP. What a foolish mistake i did. Thank you David for helping me and saving my time to waste.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually contain the answer (which is about networking and service discovery/dns). Can you update the answer so that others reading it in the future can understand the root issue here. Thx.

Comment: Added an update to the answer above to cite the conclusion